# Robot in Rviz flashes

Tags: ros, rviz, urdf, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using my URDF file (for my custom robot) for simulation in rviz, then publishing state (based on the odo data coming from real robot) robot moves in RVIZ in accordance with real robot, but the robot in rviz keeps on flashing..?

any reason why this happens..?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189839/robot-in-rviz-flashes../) by [sumanth](https://answers.ros.org/users/18196/sumanth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86 on 2014-08-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This might be due to a bad tf issue (if you have 2 different parent for the robot for example). Can you make sure the published tf are OK?

```
rosrun tf view_frames    # then look at the generated frames.pdf
roswtf                   # might also tell you if there's an issue with the tf tree.
```

---

Originally posted by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) with karma: 1620 on 2014-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sumanth](https://answers.ros.org/users/18196/sumanth/) on 2014-08-13**:
When I run roswtf I get the following error:

ERROR TF multiple authority contention:

- node [/my_state_publisher_temp] publishing transform [base_link] with parent [odom] already published by node [/odometry_publisher]
- node [/odometry_publisher] publishing transform [base_link] with parent [odom] already published by node [/my_state_publisher_temp]

**Comment by [sumanth](https://answers.ros.org/users/18196/sumanth/) on 2014-08-13**:
Now I got the problem, If I stop the /odometry_publisher node, the robot is moving fine in rviz.

**Comment by [sumanth](https://answers.ros.org/users/18196/sumanth/) on 2014-08-13**:
Thanks for the insights

**Comment by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on 2014-08-13**:
great, can you accept the answer to close the thread?